# How to use groupby on day and month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

I have a timeseries data for a full year for every minute.

```
timestamp               day hour min somedata           
2010-01-01 00:00:00     1   0   0       x
2010-01-01 00:01:00     1   0   1       x
2010-01-01 00:02:00     1   0   2       x
2010-01-01 00:03:00     1   0   3       x
2010-01-01 00:04:00     1   0   4       x
...                            ...
2010-12-31 23:55:00     365 23  55  
2010-12-31 23:56:00     365 23  56  
2010-12-31 23:57:00     365 23  57  
2010-12-31 23:58:00     365 23  58  
2010-12-31 23:59:00     365 23  59
```

I want to `group-by` the data based on the day, i.e `2010-01-01` data should be one group, `2010-01-02` should be another upto `2010-12-31`.

I used `daily_groupby = dataframe.groupby(pd.to_datetime(dataframe.index.day, unit='D', origin=pd.Timestamp('2009-12-31')))`. This creates the group based on the days so all `jan, feb upto dec 01 day are in one group`. But I want to also group by using month so that `jan, feb ..` does not get mixed up.
I am a beginner in pandas.

Answer (score 2):

if `timestamp` is the index use  [`DatetimeIndex.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html)

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).date)
```

else [`Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.date)
```

If you don't want group by **year** use:

```
time_index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby([time_index.month,time_index.day])
```

Comment: Here actually timestamp is the index.